# How to render uniform thick stripes with GLSL on an animated mesh

Tags: opengl, glsl, webgl

I have a 3d model and I'd like to make a shader that shades the model with stripes where the stripes are rgba(1,1,1,1) and rgba(0,0,0,0).  Assume the model will get scaled non-uniformly, I'd like the rgba(1,1,1,1) stripes to stay a uniform thickness in screenspace.

Imagine I have a model of a head and I apply a horizontally striped texture to it such that all the lines in that initial state are a uniform thickness. If I don't do anything else, as the head stretches/scales/animates the lines will get thinner and thicker as the polygons they are on stretch.

Can you imagine a way so that one of the 2 colors of lines never changes thickness relative to the screen? The other color is allowed to stretch.

For example, I could shade them in worldspace. That would make the lines stay the same size but the lines would not move with the model. Instead it would look like the lines are being projected on the model.  Rather I want the lines to move with the model but 1 of the 2 colors to never change thickness relative to the screen (or world might be ok too)

Ideas?

Comment: Are the stripes a uniform thickness in this scenario to begin with? Before the non-uniform scaling of the model, that is. Because you can easily scale vertex coordinates and texture coordinates independently to maintain such a property. The funny thing is, until I read the last paragraph I was going to suggest texture projection. I still would not rule this out, because it is easy to translate the center of projection to track the model you are trying to stripe.

Comment: I don't think scaling the vertex coords will work unless no vertices are shared. Take a typical 4 quad plain (8 triangles). At least 4 triangles all share the center vertex. Adjusting that vertex's UV for each triangle won't work will it? Maybe that's the solution though, give them each their own UVs? Even then, how do you know how much to scale each UV. It seems like you'd need to know the positions of the other 2 vertices in the triangle in order to know the ultimate size the triangle will take. I'm not sure you could scale each UV independently.